# Showing a ring is Artinian?

Tags: ring-theory, artinian

We have a ring

$R=\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z} & 0 \\ \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \end{pmatrix}$

Let $I=\begin{pmatrix} 12\mathbb{Z} & 0 \\ 3\mathbb{Z} & 3\mathbb{Z} \end{pmatrix}$

How do I show that $R/I$ is Artinian ring? $R/I=I$, the only ideal that isn't equal to I is 
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 3\mathbb{Z} & 3\mathbb{Z} \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 12\mathbb{Z} & 0 \\  3\mathbb{Z} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. These are both DCC condition is satisfied with them.

So then you just conclude it's Artinian. Also, the nilradical elements are just the bottom left corner of the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying too hard. This ring is Artinian because it is *finite*: it has only $12*3*3=72$ elements.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denote the ring of integers mod $n$. The quotient is
$$
R/I=\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{Z}_{12} & 0 \\ \mathbb{Z}_3 & \mathbb{Z}_3 \end{pmatrix}
$$